# Selecting if all row ids exists in other table with column check

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `sites` and `callback_votes` where sites holds the available sites to vote on, and `callback_votes` holds the votes that has been done on each site.

callback_votes is structured like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/7aa672895bc2fb76cdf54539558ec221.png))</sub>

Each time someone votes, the callback adds a new `callback_votes` row with the site id he voted on into site_id and the username, ip address he voted from.

Now what I want to do is, check if user has voted on all sites in the table sites by going through ***all*** `callback_votes` rows for the given ip, and check if it's `site_id` **matches** in the `sites` table.

*Here's what I tried to do:*

```
SELECT sites.* 
FROM sites 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM callback_votes 
    WHERE callback_votes.ip = '127.0.0.1') = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM sites);
```

But this query won't work how I want, it only checks if there are the same count of votes with that ip as the number of rows on the sites table, which is cheat-able.

How can I do it the way I described?

EDIT;

My websites provides the sites to vote on, each site has its own id in the sites table. To vote on a site, the user clicks on the site (I load all site buttons using the sites table) and it sends him to the site's page. Once the user has voted, the site he voted on sends a callback to my site, and my site will create a new row in callback_votes with the site id he voted on, his ip and username.

Now I want to check if user has voted on all available sites by checking if the count of the votes in callback_votes is same, and the site_id matches to each other to prevent cheating.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?  That can really help explain complicated logic.

Comment: If you make sure that `(site_id, ip)` are unique then it won't be cheatable anymore. But then you need to handle a second voting attempt in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the number of sites that are not in distinct number of sites in callback where ip is user's ip:

```
Select count(*) From sites 
Where site_id NOT IN (Select DISTINCT site_id From callback_votes Where ip='1.0.0.127')
```

This will return count of sites not yet voted by this ip. If count is 0, then user has voted all.

Comment: I don't see `all row ids exist` logic in the solution

Answer (score 1):

Check the count is 0 from

```
select Count(*) from Sites
where Site_id NOT IN
(select Site_id from Votes where votes.user_ip = '127.0.0.1')
```

You can get the list of non voted sites too with the same cost by using

```
select Site_id from Sites
where Site_id NOT IN
(select Site_id from Votes where votes.user_ip = '127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(DISTINCT(c.site_id)) = (SELECT COUNT(s.site_id) FROM sites s), 'true', 'false') as voted_all
FROM callback_votes c
WHERE c.ip='127.0.0.1';
```

This returns true if they voted on every site and false if they didn't.

Comment: Hmm it still returns false if I have all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IP, USERNAME, CASE COUNT(DISTINCT SITE_ID) WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM SITES) THEN 'VOTED FOR ALL' ELSE 'OTHER' END
FROM callback_votes
GROUP BY IP, USERNAME
```