# SQL select count of items that not in other table with additional column check

Tags: mysql, sql

The title doesn't make sense because it's hard to explain what I want in the title, [you can read this because it was explained and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964041/selecting-if-all-row-ids-exists-in-other-table-with-column-check)

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing
FROM sites
WHERE id NOT IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT site_id
             FROM callback_votes
             WHERE ip='84.108.27.143')
```

This returns the amount of sites that haven't been voted on, returns 0 if voted on all. (see the link, it's explained)

But in the database, I have site type that has a column named `module`, so what I want to do  is, check if sites.module equals to 'none', then count it as NOT IN, like it does in that query.

So let's say you have 2 sites in the db, you never voted for any - this query will return `2` but with the 'none' check, it will only return `1` because one of the sites have module set to 'none'. [Very similar to what I asked few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980350/sql-checking-if-exists-in-other-table-if-not-then-check-its-type), but it's pretty complex in this case

I tried doing things like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing
FROM sites
WHERE id NOT IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT site_id
             FROM callback_votes
             WHERE ip='84.108.27.143')
         OR module = 'none'
```

But no luck.

**Is there a way to do this in this query?**

Comment: Can you provide some examples to explain the logic you want?  I don't understand why your query isn't doing what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The first query I showed, does what I want(ed), but now I've added a column called 'module' which can have values, but if the column module has the value 'none' then the query won't count it as a not voted site (AS missing) in this case. So lets say you have 2 rows, 1 without module value, and is not in callback_votes and one with module 'none'. The result from the query I want will be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, you could change your `not in` to a `not exists` and include the logic there.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing
FROM sites s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM callback_votes cv
                  WHERE ip = '84.108.27.143' AND cv.site_id = s.id and s.module <> 'none'
                 );
```

But then again, I think this is equivalent to your original logic (unless some of the fields can take on `NULL` values.  Perhaps this gets you want you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing
FROM sites
WHERE id NOT IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT site_id
             FROM callback_votes
             WHERE ip='84.108.27.143') AND
      module <> 'none';
```

Comment: This works like a charm, need to learn what <> means though. Thanks.

Comment: @BenBeri It's the same as !=